# switch from bitlocker to LVM encryption

Tags: linux, debian, encryption, bitlocker, lvm

I am planning to switch to Debian Linux as a daily driver!
my only concern is my data present on the D: partition which I used Microsoft bit locker to encrypt the whole D: partition. can some one point me to the best way to encrypt my data in a way compatible with Linux such as migrating to encrypted LVM?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your first step will be to disable (not suspend) BitLocker protection.

Comment: "Migrating" is nonsense. Backup the files, do not reuse a NTFS partition if you don't intend to keep Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BitLocker *is* compatible with Linux. A recent enough `cryptsetup` will open "BITLK" devices the same way as with standard LUKS. For older systems, you can choose between `dislocker` and `libbde-utils`. (I would avoid using it for anything more than read-only access though.)

But there is no tool for direct conversion from one system to another. If you want to use LUKS, then you'll need to back up data to another filesystem, delete the BitLocker partition and re-create a LUKS volume in its place, and finally copy all data back in.

(Such a tool *could* exist in theory – it would probably be very similar to how the existing 'cryptsetup-reencrypt' works, although currently that tool only supports plain⇆LUKS conversion.)

Also, LVM doesn't actually have an encryption feature – "LVM encryption" is just how the Debian installer calls LVM inside a LUKS (cryptsetup) volume. For data filesystems it'll be easier to use bare LUKS without LVM.